# Zeppelin JDBC interpreter is giving error in version 0.9.0-preview1

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

I am working on upgrading zeppelin from 0.8.0 to 0.9.0. While setting up JDBC interpreter to access Postgres databases I am getting an error.

I created "JDBC.postgres" interpreter in zeppelin GUI and ran a query. Its giving the following error.

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.AbstractInterpreter.getZeppelinContext()Lorg/apache/zeppelin/interpreter/BaseZeppelinContext; 
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.AbstractInterpreter.interpret(AbstractInterpreter.java:32) 
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:103) 
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:676) 
at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterServer$InterpretJob.jobRun(RemoteInterpreterServer.java:569) 
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:172) 
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.AbstractScheduler.runJob(AbstractScheduler.java:121) 
at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.ParallelScheduler.lambda$runJobInScheduler$0(ParallelScheduler.java:39) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

However, the same setup was working fine in version 0.8.0

JDBC interpreter dependencies:

```
/usr/lib/zeppelin/interpreter/jdbc
rw-rr- 1 root root 8866 Apr 7 21:24 slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 32119 Apr 7 21:24 slf4j-api-1.7.10.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 648487 Apr 7 21:24 postgresql-9.4-1201-jdbc41.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 489884 Apr 7 21:24 log4j-1.2.17.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 108036 Apr 7 21:24 commons-pool2-2.2.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 167962 Apr 7 21:24 commons-dbcp2-2.0.1.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 46513 Apr 7 21:28 zeppelin-jdbc-0.9.0-preview1.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 60686 Apr 7 21:28 commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 499634 Apr 7 21:28 commons-lang3-3.7.jar
rw-rr- 1 root root 54423 Apr 7 21:28 commons-exec-1.3.jar
```

I am using Amazon EMR version 6.0.0. Zeppelin is installed during cluster creation. Once the cluster is up I updated a variable in conf/zeppelin-env.sh to access artifactory for dependencies. Modified interpreter-list file to download zeppelin-jdbc-0.9.0-preview1.jar.

After making the above stated changes I installed jdbc interpreter using the following command.

```
sudo /usr/lib/zeppelin/bin/install-interpreter.sh -n jdbc
```

Then I used zeppelin GUI to create postgress interpreter and run the commands.

Could anyone let me know how this be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to use Athena with Zeppelin jdbc interpreter using EMR 6.0.0 and Zeppelin 0.9.0.

Looks like the Zeppelin snapshot version used by EMR has an `AbstractInterpreter` requiring a method with signature `public abstract ZeppelinContext getZeppelinContext();`. While the interface implemented by `JDBCInterpreter` in `zeppelin-jdbc-0.9.0-preview1.jar` implements `public abstract BaseZeppelinContext getZeppelinContext();`. Thus the `AbstractMethodException` gets thrown.

Sooner or later the AWS EMR team should fix this, but I was able to grab an updated `zeppelin-interpreter-shaded-0.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` from maven and use it to replace `zeppelin-interpreter-api-0.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar` and seemed to work.

```
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/zeppelin/zeppelin-interpreter-shaded/0.9.0-preview1/zeppelin-interpreter-shaded-0.9.0-preview1.jar
sudo cp zeppelin-interpreter-shaded-0.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /usr/lib/zeppelin/interpreter/zeppelin-interpreter-api-0.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Then just kill/restart the Zeppelin Interpreter and should be good to go!